# Flutter: how to call setState() in onPressed() from separate Widget method

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to this `Flutter`

I am trying to change `FlatButton` text while `onPressed`. My page design in separate `Widget` method, so unable to add `setState()` in `onPressed`.

I have searched a lot. But, couldn't find. Kindly help me on this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int number = 10;

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Lists'),
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF000000),
      ),
      body: DynamicChange(),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicChange extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StateDynamic createState() => StateDynamic();
} // Class SecondRoute

class StateDynamic extends State<DynamicChange> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: thisScreenNeeds(),
    );
  }
}

Widget thisScreenNeeds() {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 50),
      child: FlatButton(
    child: Text(
      number.toString(),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: (TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 60, color: Colors.green)),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
       // Unable to add, setState(). Throwing error.
    },
  ));
}
```

**Attempt 1**

```
onPressed: () {
      // Error: The member 'setState' can only be used within instance members of subclasses
      StateDynamic().setState(() {
        number = number + 1;
   });
},
```

**Attempt 2**

```
class StateDynamic extends State<DynamicChange> {

.....
.........

void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      number++;
    });
  }

.....
.......

}

onPressed: StateDynamic()._incrementCounter,

// Run Time Error: 
   This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a 
   widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. 
   It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, 
   since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is 
   initially created.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep the method inside `State` class. Also better keep the `number` variable inside that class too. You can `setState` directly only inside the `State` class so that's why.

In your case, solution

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Lists'),
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF000000),
      ),
      body: DynamicChange(),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicChange extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StateDynamic createState() => StateDynamic();
} // Class SecondRoute

class StateDynamic extends State<DynamicChange> {
  int number = 10;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: thisScreenNeeds(),
    );
  }

  Widget thisScreenNeeds() {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 50),
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            number.toString(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: (TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 60,
                color: Colors.green)),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              number++;
            });
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

If you need to seperate widgets completely(as I understand first), you can send `VoidCallback` parameter via constructors. Like:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String text = 'Some text';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(text),
          ButtonWidget(stateSetter),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void stateSetter() {
    setState(() {
      text = 'Changed text';
    });
  }
}

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback stateSetter;

  ButtonWidget(this.stateSetter);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: this.stateSetter,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Widget thisScreenNeeds() {
  return Container();}, I have used separate widget for Button. Will it work ?

Comment: Try it. callbacks may confuse at start but it's pretty easy.

Comment: Widget thisScreenNeeds() { return Container();} , is this way wrong?

Comment: @McDonal_11 Yea, sorry I didn't read your question fully, answered mostly based on topic, solution is actually easy. I'll share now.

Comment: So, instead of **Widget thisScreenNeeds()** , **class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {}** , this way is proper? Kindly clarify me in this.

Comment: @McDonal_11 I added soluition based on your code, you can create completely different widget based on Stateless or Stateful or you can use method, but it must be inside State class.

Comment: I am stupid. I have written that Widget thisScreenNeeds() out of scope. So I faced this issue. Now resolved.

Comment: @McDonal_11 If your problem is solved, please accept the right answer and close the issue: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot. If any doubt for me, I can msg u from this comment. Pls guide me.